# How to get the OData V4 EDM when you have a model in Entity Framework 6.1.3?

Tags: entity-framework-6, odata, asp.net-web-api2

As the subject goes: How to get the OData V4 EDM when you have a model in Entity Framework 6.1.3?

I do not mean OData V3, but specifically OData V4.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Restier` is what you're looking for.

https://github.com/OData/RESTier

Comment: Now I have taken a look at it. Actually it looks quite promissing but also quite immature. For instance the $metadata document does not have correct handling of abstract entities, entities which specialize base entities and concurrency properties are not marked as they should be etc. There was an updated version posted a few days ago, I hope for an updated version soon.